# $sum in mongodb sums decimals, the result is an integer, the number behind the decimal point is forcibly removed, solve?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The data in the database is like this, there are decimals, I need to sum.
the data:

```js
[ { _id: 5ad16497f52e0e1160fb70ae,
    state: 0,
    percentage: 32,
    serviceCharge: 1 },
  { _id: 5ad16600f52e0e1160fb70b1,
    state: 0,
    percentage: 0,
    serviceCharge: 10.115384615384642 },
  { _id: 5ad167f6c782521402300b4a,
    state: 0,
    percentage: 0,
    serviceCharge: 16.11538461538464 },
  { _id: 5ad167f9c782521402300b4c,
    state: 0,
    percentage: 0,
    serviceCharge: 23.769230769230717 },
  { _id: 5ad49154eb7bc9401e0c469b,
    state: 0,
    percentage: 6,
    serviceCharge: 6 },
  { _id: 5ad49154eb7bc9401e0c469c,
    state: 2,
    percentage: 0,
    serviceCharge: 6 } ]
```

the code :

```js
bet.aggregate(
  {
    $match: {
      state: { $in: [0, 1, 2, 3] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { state: "$state" },
      serviceCharge: { $sum:  "$serviceCharge" },
      percentage: { $sum: "$percentage" },
      income:{ $sum: { $subtract: [ "$serviceCharge","$percentage"] } }
    },
  },
  { $project: { "_id": 0, "state": "$_id.state", "serviceCharge": 1, "percentage": 1 ,"income":1} },
  (err, ret) => {
    console.log(ret)
  })
```

Run, and the result is :

```js
[
{ serviceCharge: 6, percentage: 0, income: 6, state: 2 },
{ serviceCharge: 57, percentage: 38, income: 19, state: 0 }
]
```

Where is my Decimals, and Why is the result of the calculation an integer?

Comment: It actually is `57` Or `56.9999999999999999` depending on the level of precision in your calculator. Do we really need to discuss the whole ["floating point math problem"](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/) again? If you are using MongoDB 3.4 ( and you should be at least ) then you might want to look at the [BSON Decimal type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal), if that `0.0000000000001` is really that important to you.

Comment: What is your schema?